# Connect/bridge two networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge, bridge-router, bridging

#### Summary

I have two networks, that I wan't to connect to each other, so I can connect from one machine on one network to another machine on another network.

#### How things are

At my office, I have a wireless network that I have very limited control over (no port forwarding etc). But it's reliable, no data limit, and fast. Connected to this network I have a server (Mac Mini).

Then I have another server (Linux Desktop), which is connected to my own mobile network through a Teletonika RUT950 modem/router. Here I have full control, and can do port forwarding etc.

#### What I want to achieve

I can currently SSH into the Linux machine on my own mobile network, but I would love to also be able to SSH (and VNC etc) into the Mac Mini which is on the other corporate network. I can't connect the Mac Mini to the mobile network, because of expense/data limits.

**How can I do this?** I might be able to connect with cable to the office network, but preferably over wifi. The Linux, Mac Mini and the RUT950 can be co-located.

I would prefer a general solution that maybe uses some native functionality of the RUT950 or something, rather than specialized software setup or similar. But open to anything.

[image]

Comment: It might help to draw a diagram. Are you saying you want to bridge them wirelessly? I.e the two networks are within 300ft of each other?

Comment: All I wan't is to connect/SSH from the "Linux machine" (wired on "Network A"), to the Mac Mini (wireless on "Network B"). Simplest solution would be the best.

Comment: Added diagram to original post. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I might be able to connect with cable to the office network, but preferably over wifi.

You need one machine somewhere that is connected to both networks. This can be a machine with two WLAN adapters (or one WLAN adapter that can connect to both WLAN networks at once, but these are rare), or a machine with a WLAN and a LAN.

If you have control over your Mac Mini, the simplest solution would be to connect the LAN on the Mac Mini to the LAN on the RUT950.

Depending on what variant you choose, you'll then have to configure various things (like IP ranges, routes, and so on). If you have control over the Mac Mini and can connect its LAN to the RUT950, the Mac Mini will get two IP address (one in each network), and you just have to make sure that sshd is active on both to be able to ssh into it.

Also, assuming the "wireless network that I have very limited control over" is a corporate network, they usually don't like that their networks get routed to open networks, and may act if they find out you did.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, I would suggest *not* connecting the two networks at all. Instead connect the *hosts* to a common network.

If you have an *externally accessible* server somewhere, set up a VPN service that both your office computer and the personal network connect to. All hosts connected to the VPN will be able to reach each other; the server will relay traffic between them.

Any generic VPN protocol will do, such as OpenVPN or Wireguard; the "Innernet" software looks promising as well.

(On the "personal" side you can have the router itself connect to the VPN, though I'm not sure what the RUT is capable of.)

In addition to basic server-based VPNs, there are also kinda "mesh" VPNs such as Tinc or ZeroTier, which have various levels of sophistication for delivering packets through NATs, relays, firewalls, etc. If you *don't* have a suitable central server, then one of these might work better.